# Serve forced desktop view to IE8 with Susy2

Tags: susy-sass

sorry if missed in the docs but can Susy2 be used for IE8 users with respond.js or other techniques, ie to force a desktop view only, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Susy can be used with any media-query solution you want. We have built in some shortcuts if you want to use Susy with [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/), but you can use whatever technique you prefer.